# October CMS create a UUID default value trigger using migrations

Tags: php, mysql, database-migration, uuid, octobercms

How to create new type for migrations in October CSM?
I found [this topic](https://octobercms.com/forum/post/creating-a-uuid-for-your-data-table-using-migrations-in-october), but it doesn't work for me.

I just want to write something like this in my migration file:

```html
$table->engine = 'InnoDB';
$table->increments('id')->unsigned();
$table->uuid('uid');
$table->string('name')->nullable();
```

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED
I was a little bit inattentive. Example in that topic works fine. I tried one more time and corrected some variable names.

But problem of creation of a new type for database migrations still persists. How to make it possible $table->uuid('unique_id'); ?